# Why discriminant result in R (lda) and SPSS are different?

Tags: r, spss

I tried to perform a discriminant analysis with `lda` in R and in SPSS, but, the scaling are different.

how to get (**Constant**) with R like SPSS result?

```
head(data)

#      smoke age selfcon anxiety absence subtestb
# 1        1  36      42      17       3       30
# 2        1  45      45      21       0       29
# 3        1  43      36      13       8       23
# 4        2  25      25      23      14       20
# 5        2  36      32      25       9       16
# 6        2  25      19      27       5       20
```

lda() result

```
lda(x,cl)$scaling
                LD1
age      -0.0237009
selfcon  -0.0800297
anxiety   0.0999290
absence   0.0115092
subtestb -0.1341198
```

SPSS result:

```
age            .024
selfcon        .080
anxiety score −.100
absence       −.012
subtestb       .134
(Constant)   −4.543
```

why at SPSS have Constant and R not?

Comment: Only the sign is different right? And alternate the same way between R and SPSS. I would say results are identical.

Comment: right the sign is different

Comment: Have you written to the authors of SPSS that result of their package differs from R's?

Comment: no..why SPSS have constant and R not?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166942/why-are-discriminant-analysis-results-in-r-lda-and-spss-different-constant-t (where there is an answer)